# How to create a table header with th span in two first columns?

Tags: html, html-table

Please look at this:

[jsfiddle.net/hTRQJ/](http://jsfiddle.net/hTRQJ/)

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped"><thead>
            <tr>
                <th colpan="">
                    Checkin
                </th>
                <th>
                    Checkout
                </th>

                <th>
                    Description
                </th>
                <th>Total</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody><tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>2013-03-28 19:19:00</td>
        <td>2013-03-28 19:35:00</td>
        <td>Implementatie OAuth</td>
        <td>00:16</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>2013-03-28 19:19:00</td>
        <td>2013-03-28 19:20:00</td>
        <td>Site werkt niet</td>
        <td>00:01</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>2013-03-28 19:15:00</td>
        <td>2013-03-28 19:42:00</td>
        <td>apache recompile</td>
        <td>00:27</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>2013-03-28 19:14:00</td>
        <td>2013-03-28 19:47:00</td>
        <td>Site werkt niet</td>
        <td>00:33</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>2013-03-28 19:12:00</td>
        <td>2013-03-28 19:37:00</td>
        <td>Site werkt niet</td>
        <td>00:25</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>2013-03-28 19:08:00</td>
        <td>2013-03-28 19:36:00</td>
        <td>apache recompile</td>
        <td>00:28</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>2013-03-28 19:07:00</td>
        <td>2013-03-28 19:39:00</td>
        <td>Git repos</td>
        <td>00:32</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>2013-03-28 19:05:00</td>
        <td>2013-03-28 19:34:00</td>
        <td>Server failure</td>
        <td>00:29</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td colspan="4"><span style="float:right">Total</span></td><td>03:11</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I want that 'test' is in the same column as the first datetime. What do I need to change?

EDIT:

I want it like this; http://s7.postimg.org/yb4hppnfv/Knipsel.png
So what you see in the last colum, that effect, I want it in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want the "test" td to span two columns, into the datetimes?

Then you would add the colspan attribute to the td test, and set it to "2".

```
<tr> <td colspan="2">test</td> </tr>
```

Like that, it should move over a space.

Comment: No, I want the first datetime in the same column as test, so 'Checkin' = test + first datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the header and the first two lines of your table. The rest can be done according the same rules.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped"><thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colpan="2">
                                            Checkin/Checkout
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Description
                                        </th>
                                        <th>Total</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody><tr>
                                <td colspan="2">test 2013-03-28 19:19:00</td>
                                <td>2013-03-28 19:35:00</td>
                                <td>Implementatie OAuth</td>
                                <td>00:16</td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td colspan="2">test 2013-03-28 19:19:00</td>
                                <td>2013-03-28 19:20:00</td>
                                <td>Site werkt niet</td>
                                <td>00:01</td>
                            </tr><tr>
```

Comment: Perhaps I could clear it up with this; http://s7.postimg.org/yb4hppnfv/Knipsel.png
What you see in the last column, I want it in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

In total , you need to have the name number of cells (td = 5) and th colspans (2 + 1 + 2 = 5).

Here are the first two rows:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped"><thead>
    <tr>
    <th colspan = "2">
        Checkin/Checkout
    </th>
    <th>
        Description
    </th>
    <th colspan = "2">Total</th>                                    
    <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>2013-03-28 19:19:00</td>
    <td>2013-03-28 19:35:00</td>
    <td>Implementatie OAuth</td>
    <td>00:16</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>2013-03-28 19:19:00</td>
    <td>2013-03-28 19:20:00</td>
    <td>Site werkt niet</td>
    <td>00:01</td>
</tr>></tr></tbody></table>
```